# не работает викторина, не могу найти ошибку

Tags: python

Помогите найти ошибку в коде:

```
import sys
def open_file(file, mode):
    """открывает фаил"""
    try:
        the_file = open(file, mode, encoding='utf-8')
    except IOError as e:
        print("не возможно открыть фаил", file, "программа будет завершена", e )
        input("нажмите Enter to exit")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    category = next_line(the_file)
    question = next_line(the_file)
    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))
        correct = next_line(the_file)
        if correct:
            correct = correct[0]
            explanation = next_line(the_file)
    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation
def welcome(title):
    print("Добро пожаловать!  ")
    print("\t\t, title, \n")

def main():
    trivia_file = open_file("file.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i+1, "-", answers[1])
        answers = input("ваш ответ: ")
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nYes", end=" ")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nнет", end=" ")
            print(explanation)
            print("Счет: ", score, "\n\n")
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(trivia_file)
        trivia_file.close()
print("это был последний вопрос")
print("на вашем счету: ", score)
main()
input()
```