# Не работает игра. Где-то спряталась ошибка и я не могу найти ее

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите найти ошибку в коде:

```
import sys
def open_file(file, mode):
    """Открывает файл"""
    try:
        the_file = open(file, mode, encoding='utf-8')
    except IOError as e:
        print("невозможно открыть файл:", file, "программа будет завершена", e )
        input("нажмите Enter to exit")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    """ возвращает в отформатированном виде очередную строку игрового файла """
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    """ возвращает очередной блог данных из игрового файла """
    category = next_line(the_file)
    question = next_line(the_file)
    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))
        correct = next_line(the_file)
        if correct:
            correct = correct[0]
            explanation = next_line(the_file)
    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation
def welcome(title):
    print("Добро пожаловать!  ")
    print("\t\t, title, \n")

def main():
    trivia_file = open_file("file.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0
```

Comment: уточните вопрос или предоставьте тестовые данные. По return category, question, answers, correct, explanation - не ясно почему именно так решили делать.

Comment: Ответил в этой теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694320/

Answer (score 1):

Ты вызываешь функцию main() после того, как выводишь результат, поэтому функция print не распознаёт переменную score. А также, если ты назначаешь переменной значение в функции, то оно будет локальным, а надо сделать его глобальным (global score). У меня нету файла твоей игры, но у тебя также есть ошибка с отступами. Цикл for i in range(4) должен только записывать данные в файл, а у тебя он 4 раза достаёт другие данные. 
Вот так должен выглядеть твой год

```html
import sys
def open_file(file, mode):
    """открывает фаил"""
    try:
        the_file = open(file, mode, encoding='utf-8')
    except IOError as e:
        print("не возможно открыть фаил", file, "программа будет завершена", e )
        input("нажмите Enter to exit")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    category = next_line(the_file)
    question = next_line(the_file)
    answers = []
    for i in range(4):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))
    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]
        explanation = next_line(the_file)
    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation
def welcome(title):
    print("Добро пожаловать!  ")
    print("\t\t, title, \n")

def main():
    global score
    trivia_file = open_file("file.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        print(category)
        print(question)
        for i in range(4):
            print("\t", i+1, "-", answers[1])
        answer = input("ваш ответ: ")
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nYes", end=" ")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nнет", end=" ")
            print(explanation)
            print("Счет: ", score, "\n\n")
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation = next_block(trivia_file)
        trivia_file.close()
main()
print("это был последний вопрос")
print("на вашем счету: ", score)

input()
```

Answer (score 0):

`correct` и `explanation` создаются 4 раза внутри цикла `for i in range(4)`. Соответствунно `return` вернет последнее из них

```
for i in range(4):
    answers.append(next_line(the_file))
    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]
        explanation = next_line(the_file)
return category, question, answers, correct, explanation
```

- структура файла `file.txt` плоха, ошибка может быть в ней. Лучше хранить все, например в `dict`, а читать и записывать его в файл с помощью `pickle`